# duplicate udp packets: how often it happens?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am developing a protocol over UDP to be used in a local network, there will be only a switch (cisco, 3com, etc) between source and destination, both Linux systems, same MTU.
How often should I expect udp packets to be duplicated (obviously not by me but by the switch or maybe the server) at the destination in this case? I need this to know if to implement a duplication check in my code or not.

Comment: Probably not too often, but I wouldn't base my program on this assumption. Why don't you just use TCP?

Comment: Is there any logical explanation why (and how) should local switch clone UDP packet?

Comment: I have found numerous references on internet that udp packets may be duplicated, honestly neither I understand why this should happen in a local network , this is why I am asking.

Comment: I just found a way to check for duplicates which won't cost me more than a few memory reads and without a need for any sequential numbers (which would kill udp). The solution is to keep circular buffer of the packet's index on the server in the exact order as the client has it. Client will send its index_num along with request_id. If a duplicate packet comes in the server will get request_id from the index_num and drop the packet if request_id is the same. request_id is incremented per request. Very simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Switches will send packets to all interfaces when using broadcasts or under extreme conditions (full MAC Address Table). This can lead to duplication if there is a loop between two or more switches and if the Spanning Tree Protocol is not used. So the answer is rarely.

Answer (score 3):

From memory of a story I've read ~20 years ago...

There was a faulty router that duplicated UDP packets. Long story short it was found that some interrupt was raised excessively frequently. That caused the following scenario:

1. The router went to the outgoing packets queue
2. It sent the packet and before it marked it as sent...
3. An interrupt was raised.
4. For some reason, after handling the interrupt, the router went back to check the outgoing packet queue, rather than marking the packet as sent (an unrelated bug?), causing it to retransmit the same packet until the interval between the interrupts was long enough to finish step 2.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility to receive duplicate UDP packets in destination host depends on number of destination interfaces that receives the packet from the source host. The destination will receive three duplicate UDP packets if three of its interfaces(eth1, eth2, eth_int) can fetch the packets from source at same time.

Comment: But all those interfaces (eth1,eth2, etc) can't use the same IP address, so there shouldn't be duplicates in the case you are describing.

Comment: If the socket in the destination host is bound to INADDR_ANY and if the source broadcast the UDP packets then there is possibility to receive duplicate packets.

Comment: but I am not talking about this kind of duplication. I am talking about the switch/router or kernel re transmitting packet without my concern. This may happen easily if packets travel through many routers, but I am talking about local network

Comment: -1. It depends on a lot more things than that, and the source isn't broadcasting, it is multicasting, so the interfaces will only receive packets each if they have each joined the multicast group.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually suffering some issues on an application since I haven't implemented checks to avoid duplicated packets.

**Adding a simple increment check wouldn't work as expected sometimes.** Why? Routers can change the inbound/outbound routes for UDP packets easily even in real time, wich can cause a delay in some packets. This can cause the next scenario:

- Program A send 3 UDP packets with the incremental IDs 1, 2 and 3 to Program B.
- Program B receives the UDP Packets in the order 2, 1 and 3. Not what you would expect.

**So, instead I am betting in same-same-but-different mechanism:**

- Add a few random values in your packet.
- Generate a checksum of the packet when your program receive them.
- Save the last N checksums (Ex.: N=100) of the packets.
- Every time you get a packet, search for a duplicated checksum in your list. **Discard if found.**

Hopefully this will help you avoid duplicated packets completely. It doesn't matter if your protocol it's un/encrypted, the random values will help you to get unique checksums (hopefully you won't have a checksum collision in the last N packets).